# $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all positive rational numbers $(a,b)$ so that:
>
> $$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$$

To solve this problem the first thing comes to my mind is squaring both sides:

$$a+b+2\sqrt{ab}=2+\sqrt{3}$$
I equated $a+b=2$ and $ab=\frac34$ :
$$a,b=\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt{4-3}}{2}$$

$(a,b)\in\{(\frac32,\frac12),(\frac12,\frac32)\}$

Is it true?

Comment: Because your squaring is wrong, see the RHS.

Comment: $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac12}+\sqrt{\frac32}$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I fixed it . is my answer correct now?

Comment: It is hard to see a rational "b" come out of this with "a" as input. 

$$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\implies b=a-\sqrt{8a^2+\sqrt{3}}+2+\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

You may just apply the denesting formula

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-c}}2}+ \sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-c}}2}
$$
to obtain$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac12}+\sqrt{\frac32}
$$

Comment: Nice, thank you. How do you derive that without squaring the right hand side etc?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - not sure if there is an easier derivation

Comment: So was its discovery just a sort of fluke or pattern spotting?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - not at all. There is way to derive, but not easier than just squaring

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for the clarfication. Do you know where I can find this harder derivation?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - for example, solve quadratic equation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.
On squaring, you get a+b+2√ab =2+√3

Thus a+b=25

And ab=0.75

Solving the quadratic a(2-a)=0.75, you get the solutions (a,b)=(0.5,1.5) and (1.5,0.5).

Verification:

(√0.5+√1.5)^2

=0.5+1.5 2√(0.5*1.5)

=2+2√0.75

=2+√3

Hence (√0.5+√1.5)=√(2+√3)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: J. W. Tanner, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt2}$$

Square and multiply for $\sqrt2$ from both sides and you get
$$2(a+b)+4\sqrt{ab} = 4 + 2\sqrt3$$

Here you get a system:
\begin{cases}
a+b = 2 \\
4ab=3
\end{cases}